# What is this c++ macro doing?

Tags: c++, macros

I dont see what the following macro is doing? If anyone can help me see it it would be appreciated.

```
#define BASE_OFFSET(ClassName,BaseName)\
(DWORD(static_cast < BaseName* >( reinterpret_cast\
< ClassName* >(Ox10000000)))-Ox10000000)
```

If anyone is curious to know where it is coming from, it comes out of the 3rd chapter of Don Box Book Essential COM where he is building a QueryInterface function using interface tables and the above macro is somehow used to find the pointer to the interface vtable of the class, where class is the ClassName implementing the BaseName, although I dont know how it is doing that.

Comment: It is converting address `OxlOOOOOOO` with `reinterpret_cast` then uses `static_cast` and finally cast it to `DWORD`.It is subtracting the address `OxlOOOOOOO` from the result. Now can you tell us what does the address of `OxlOOOOOOO` point to?

Comment: @Desolator- I think it's a magic number chosen so that the subtraction doesn't end up wrapping around below 0.

Comment: Just to make it clear: there is no `0` and no `1` in `OxlOOOOOOO`, just the letters `O`, `l` and `x`, right?

Comment: Seva is almost certainly right that the constant is _supposed_ to be `0x10000000` and _not_ `OxlOOOOOO`. Can the OP confirm, and edit the question to fix?

Comment: Sorry it is 0X1000000. These are the numbers 0's and 1's and not the letters 'o' and 'x'. So in the question it is a hexadeicmal number 0x1000000. Sorry I think the formatting for question came out bad.

Comment: It's also a lowercase x. It matters since C++ is case sensitive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It tells to the compiler: "imagine there a `ClassName` object at 0x10000000. Where would the `BaseName` data begin in that object, relative to 0x10000000"?

Think of a memory layout of a class object with multiple bases:

```
class A: B, C{};
```

In the memory block that constitutes an A object, there's the chunk of data that belong to B, also a chunk of data that belongs to C, and the data that are specific to A. Since the address of at least one base's data cannot be the same as the address of the class instance as a whole, the numeric value of the `this` pointer that you pass to different methods needs to vary. The macro retrieves the value of the difference.

EDIT: The pointer to the vtable is, by convention, the first data member in any class with virtual functions. So by finding the address of the base data, one finds the address of its vtable pointer.

Now, about the type conversion. Normally, when you typecast pointers, the operation is internally trivial - the numeric value of the address does not depend on what type does it point to; the very notion of datatype only exists on the C level. There's one important exception though - when you cast object pointers with multiple inheritance. As we've just discussed, the `this` pointer that you need to pass to a base class method might be numerically different from the one of the derived object's.

So the distinction between static_cast and reinterpret_cast captures this difference neatly. When you use reinterpret_cast, you're telling the compiler: "I know better. Take this numeric value and interpret it as a pointer to what I say". This is a deliberate subversion of the type system, dangerous, but occasionally necessary. This kind of cast is by definition trivial - cause you say so.

By "trivial" I mean - the numeric value of the pointer does not change.

The static_cast is a more high level construct. In this particular case, you're casting between an object and its base. That's a reasonable, safe cast under C++ class rules - BUT it might be numerically nontrivial. That's why the macro uses two different typecasts. static_cast does NOT violate the type system.

To recap:

```
reinterpret_cast<ClassName* >(OxlOOOOOOO)
```

is an unsafe operation. It returns a bogus pointer to a bogus object, but it's OK because we never dereference it.

```
static_cast<BaseName*>(...)
```

is a safe operation (with an unsafe pointer, the irony). It's the part where the nontrivial pointer typecast happens.

```
(DWORD(...)-OxlOOOOOOO)
```

is pure arithmetic. That's where the unsafety doubles back on itself: rather than use the pointer as a pointer, we cast it back to an integer and forget that it ever was a pointer.

The last stage could be equivalently rephrased as:

```
((char*)(...)-(char*)OxlOOOOOOO)
```

if that makes more sense.

Comment: More concisely it's the offset of the "BaseName" data within a "ClassName" object.

Comment: Note to OP: as Seva and mydogisbox say, this is finding the offset within a `ClassName` object of the `BaseName` sub-object. This has nothing (directly) to do with the vtable.

Comment: Hey Seva, 

I understand what you are trying to say. I am just curious to know how it is achieving the effect that you mentioned using reinterpret_cast<ClassName*> and then doing a static_cast<BaseName*> on the result to get a pointer to the base class of the imaginary object instance. Thanks once again for your answer!

Comment: Feel free to accept it by clicking the checkmark next to it :) That's how we say thanks here at StackOverflow.

Comment: Hahaha, new at stackoverflow. Thanks, did it :).

Answer (score 1):

Remark about magic 0x10000000 constant.

If that constant will be 0, GCC will show warning -Winvalid-offset-of (if it is enabled, of course). Maybe other compilers do something like that.